# Changing formData of a form before submit() method is invoked

Tags: javascript, html, request, http-post, multipartform-data

I need to add some data to a form using FormData so that when the form is submitted this new piece of data is also posted, but I can't get it working. Note that I do not want to use ajax or fetch to send formData since I want the page to redirect user to a different page when he clicks the submit button.

```
                const myForm = document.querySelector('form');
                myForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    const formData = new FormData(myForm);
                    formData.append('age', '20');
                    event.target.submit();
                });
```

Comment: If you don't want to use AJAX, then don't prevent the default action of the submit event. To modify the data, you've to add the needed control elements to the form, or include a hidden field to the form and modify its value in the event handler. It's notable, that the object created by `FormData` is not linked to the original form. It's also possible to use AJAX and redirect.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments the best way to do this was to prevent the normal event, submit your own formData object and then redirect by yourself.

```js
var form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    // build up formdata
    const formData = new FormData(form);
    formData.append("age", '20');
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "submitform.php");    

    // redirect on success
    request.addEventListener('load', function( event ) {
      window.location.replace('/my-locaiton')
    });

    // Do whatever needed on error
    request.addEventListener('error', function( event ) {
      console.log('failed request..')
    });   
    
    request.send(formData);
})
```

```html
<form id="form" action="POST" target="redirect.html">
    <input type="text" value="somtext">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

If you still want to let the form do the job you could do something like this to prevent the event and then dispatch it again..
You would need to add hidden elements to the form in this case:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form')
const listener = async (e) => {

    // prevent default action.
    e.preventDefault()

    // only run the listener only once.
    form.removeListener('submit', listener)

    // append actual data..
    const ageInput = document.createElement('input')
    ageInput.style.visibility = 'hidden'
    ageInput.setAttribute('name', 'age')
    ageInput.setAttribute('value', '20')
    form.appendChild(ageInput)

    // dispatch event again!
    e.target.dispatchEvent(e)
}

form.addEventListener('submit', listener)
```

Comment: But redirecting using window.location instead of invoking form's submit() method does not post data which is needed in target page for it to render properly. That's why I'm using event.target.submit() in my snippet so redirecting and posting of data happens in one request. Window.location approach uses two requests, one post and one get which causes target page to lose context of what it needs to display.

Comment: I am aware of approach of inserting hidden input fields, but I thought FormData would allow us to avoid such tricks and adjust data in a cleaner manner. But it seems we can write data of a form to a FormData object, but not the vice versa which is not clear to me why.

Comment: @smohadjer Notice, that in this answer the data is posted with AJAX, redirection happens when the AJAX response arrives.

Comment: @Teemu It makes no difference, still when we redirect to the page with window.location the data is lost and new page can not show the data that was posted with Ajax.

Comment: @smohadjer ?? The old page is gone when you submit the form too. Like I said in my earlier comment, [FormData object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) is not linked to the form the constructor was passed, only the form control names and values are copied when the object is created. You can create a FormData object without a form too. If you want include data on the old page in the new page, you've to store it to LocalStorage, or attach it on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling for hours and finally it occurred to me " Why am I not creating another Form myself and try submitting that? You can use FormData or serializeArray() to extract the keys and values from the previous Form and append them to the new form.

let testForm = {'key1': value1, 'key2': value2} // values I want to submit with my new form

```
    function add(form, name, value) {

        //Create an input type dynamically.
        var element = document.createElement("input");
        //Assign different attributes to the element.
        element.setAttribute("value", value);
        element.setAttribute("name", name);

        //Append the element in page (in span).
        form.appendChild(element);
    }

    let myForm = document.createElement('form');

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(testForm)) {
        console.log(`${key} ${value}`);
        add(myForm, key, value)
    }

    myForm.setAttribute("action", "url")
    myForm.setAttribute("method", "POST")

    document.body.appendChild(myForm)
    myForm.submit();
```